# Conditional angular ui router views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two user flows in my angular app and steps for each flow are more similar than they are different. One particular step has multiple panels, and I want to conditionally show different panels depending on the user flow (some of the panels are common for both flows).

Obviously, the most basic solution is to have two separate states with two separate templates, but with many commonalities between them there would be a lot of duplicate code.

Another solution I see would involve creating a separate child state for each panel?

Or perhaps this is not a UI-router thing at all and I should use custom directives for each panel?

How can I use angular UI-router effectively to avoid duplicating html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters into a controller through the router.

```
     $stateProvider
        .state('xyz', {
            url: '/xyz/:hasSpecialPanel',
            templateUrl: '/panels.html'
        });
```

The parameter is expressed as: `:hasSpecialPanel`

In your controller you can access this parameter using:

```
$stateParams.hasSpecialPanel
```

So you can do a test to check the value of the parameter.

You can then show / hide panels via `ng-show` based on the state of this data.

Answer (score -1):

It's very dependent what you want to achieve.

- Directives are more like **re-usable** items with identical behavior and rely only internal information that translated to them. Their displaying is totally defined by controller of state where are they implemented. Directives are counting as content of module.
- Views are more like one of options when you have several results of one functionality. Views are counting as sub-modules of modules they appended to.

From your words I assumed that you have some kind of sidebar or header that have different appearance and that's all. I would create it as sub-module (view) only due to singularity of it. I don't think you wanna to copy your panel to each page etc. If you use `templateProvider` to define different HTML templates that will be used in some cases within only one controller that is bind to view and both of them have similar functionality - you are free to do that. Coz even if you define some methods that will be used in first template it will have no impact on another one.

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/'
    views: {
        '': {/* configuration */},
        'panel@main': {
            templateProvider: () => {/* returns template depending on condition*/},
            controller: panelController,
            controllerAs: 'panelCtrl',
            resolve: {...}
        }

    }
})
```